# Add authenticated Firebase users to Listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to add Firebase authenticated users (after entering correct username and password) to ListView. To get the better understanding here is the flow of my application.

[Here is the image of first layout when app starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueSAY.png)

1- When user clicks on Add Patient button the app redirects to another activity where the use must enter the correct email and password

2- After successful login the the app open the previous activity again(add patient activity) and add the logged in user to the ListView. Here is the xml of add patient

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/addpatient"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_48dp"
    android:drawablePadding="-170dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:text="Add Patient"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addpatient"
    android:background="#000" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listpatient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="119dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</ListView>
```

Please note that i do not want to get the list of users from Firebase Database, I'm using firebase authentication just not firebase database. here is the code of add patient activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_patient);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    addPatient = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.addpatient);
    listPatient = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listpatient);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(patient == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No user found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        patient = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        arrayList.add(String.valueOf(patient));
    }
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listPatient.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    addPatient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent it = new Intent(AddPatient.this,DoctorPanel_Signin.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
```

Problem is the listview is not showing any data. and if i remove IF statement the app is crashing by saying attempt to invoke virtual method on null pointer reference something like that. And the other thing that i'm thinking is that if i want to add 3 users then firebaseaut.getinstance.getcurrentuser will always return the 1 user and will override the previous user again and again, please consider that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are verifying if `patient == null` before the patient object is even created. So with other words your `patient object` is always null. To solve this, you need to change the logic of your if statement like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "You are signed in Firebase!");
            arrayList.add(String.valueOf(patient));
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "You are signed out from Firebase!");
        }
    }
};
```

Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
     |
     --- Users
           |
           --- userUid1
           |      |
           |      --- signedInSuccessfully: false
           |
           --- userUid2
                  |
                  --- signedInSuccessfully: true //changes after signed in successfully
```

Comment: It is crashing.. I put your code.. here is the error.. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zohai.healthapp/com.example.zohai.healthapp.DoctorPanel.AddPatient}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference

Comment: This activity is launcher activity so patient will always become null because i haven't signed in yet

Comment: patient object will get user ID after sign in process

Comment: Please see my updated answer. This is the entire code.

Comment: FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser(); this will return only current signed in user. If i want to populate the listview with multiple user than what should i do instead of firebaseAuth.getCurrentuser(); because if i again sign in with different credentials it overrides the previous user in list view

Comment: Is the modified code working now? If you want to create a list of users, then create a new node in your Firebase database named `users`, and every time a users signs in, add that user there. In the end add a listener an that node and display the users.

Comment: yes the above code works.. I have created a user node and when user sign in that user appears up in user node on firebase database. but the problem is i dont want to get all users at the same time, I just want to get user who signed in successfully and show up in list view if 3 users signed in then 3 users should show up in listview

Comment: Then create a new field for each user named `signedInSuccessfully` with the value of false. Every time a users signs in successfully, change the value to true. Then just display all the user who have the value of this new filed set to true.

Comment: Thanks i got it.. would you please share some code so that i can get better understanding how to do this

Comment: Please see my updated answer. And as i said, every time a users signs in successfully, change the value to true.